# CRUB, problem with authentication on front-end, spring security

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

4 days and i can't find any solution. I have back-end on spring boot and front-end on react. How can i make login system and session on my front-end page? I have 2 RestControllers for test.

```
@GetMapping("/protected")
    public String showProtected() {
        return "protected page";
    }

    @GetMapping("/public")
    public String showPublic(){
        return "public page";
    }
```

On server site "localhost:8080/protected and /public" everything works fine, returning login form when im not authenticated, then i can sign in with credentials. And how can i make exactly the same on my custom front page? I can only show my public page with:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/account/public")
            .then(response => this.setState({stuff: response.data}))
```

How can i make login session with custom login form on my front end page to get my protected page? It's my security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/account/protected").hasRole(USER)
                .antMatchers("/account/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/account/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token", "x-xsrf-token", "access-control-allow-headers", "access-control-allow-methods", "access-control-allow-origin"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have /account/protected protected by user hase role USER.
So you should send the token returned by authentification process to secure rout

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/protected', {
            headers: {
                'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token'),
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            resolve(res);
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(error.message);
        });
```

I hope it will be useful for you, and good luck